# How to get CSRF when Android calls API of Django

Tags: android, django, api

I'm going to use Django API for Android development use,But I met some of the following questions.

**1.Android is just giving me post form data through a URL, how can Android get csrftoken?**

**2.If post data is modified, for example, we originally need to delete the a information, but a is changed to B, which will cause the background to delete B information, and how to prevent this happening?**

**3.Where is the csrftoken of Django being stored, I looked at my database, but I didn't find it?**

I'm just beginning to learn Django, so my question may look ridiculous, but I really want someone to help me.

Answer (score 0):

you can get csrf token from

```
from django.core.context_processors import csrf

csrf_tok = csrf(request)
csrf_token =  str(csrf_tok.get('csrf_token'))
```

Comment: I am sorry that you maybe don’t understand my question....I mean that how can I get csrftoken in my android app

Comment: call a HTTP GET service, write a django view, add above code in it and return the value of csrf token as HTTPResponse, android can receive the token and send with post request

Comment: Thank you for your warm reply. It's very helpful for me. ^_^